# Xcode cannot run using the selected device on 7.1.1

Tags: xcode, profiling

I got the following error:

Xcode cannot run using the selected device.

No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

xcode 5.0.2 (5A3005) 
iphone 4S with iOS 7.1.1

Development Target is 7.0
Code signing Provisioning profile is set to IOS Team Provisioning Profile.

In Xcode -> Window -> Organizer - Devices

The version of iOS on   is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on

7.1.1 (11D201)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions

Not sure why the xcode supported IOS versions is blank here.

Already tried to project clean, remove device and reconnect and set target to lower version. None of these methods work.

Please advise.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to Xcode 5.1.1, it's working fine now.

Thx